# I cannot upload files in Laravel 8 There is no img_id in the response

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel. I can do a normal addition, but I cannot add files. What is the problem?

**Blade**

```
{!!BootForm::open([ 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'admin.companies.postCreateCompany', 'files'=> 'true'])->enctype('multipart/form-data') !!}
{!!BootForm::text('Company Name', 'company_name', null, ['required' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Company Name'])!!}
{!!BootForm::text('Name', 'owner_firstname', null, ['required' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Name'])!!}
{!!BootForm::text('Lastname', 'owner_lastname', null, ['required' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Lastname'])!!}
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="img_id" type="file" name="img_id">
</div>
{!!BootForm::text('Email', 'email', null, ['required' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Email'])!!}
{!!BootForm::submit('Save')->class('btn btn-success') !!}
{!!BootForm::close()!!}Items')->toArray();
```

**Controller**

```
public function postCreateCompany(Request $request)
{
    echo response()->json($request);
}
```

**Response**

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type:
> application/json Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2020 14:54:28 GMT

```
{"_token":"xxxxx","company_name":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","owner_firstname":null,"owner_lastname":null,"email":null}
```

There is no img_id in the response. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

I'm using plesk panel. File_uploads was disabled in php.ini. I enabled file_uploads and it was okay.

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are [handled differently](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads) than normal form fields. It won't show up by dumping `$request`.

Your file is contained in:

```
$request->file('img_id')
```

Comment: This returns a blank result. Already when I try to add it to the database it throws as null.